# Javascript RegEx: extract part of an url

Tags: javascript, regex

```
        if ((urlStr.indexOf('t='))!=-1)
        {
            var pat = /t=(\d+)m(\d+)s/;
            pat.exec(urlStr);
            alert (RegExp.$1);
            alert (RegExp.$2);

        }
```

case 1: `http://localhost/proc1/commit.php&t=1m13s` 
Returns 1 and 13 -> Okay

case 2: `http://localhost/proc1/commit.php&t=13s` 
Returns blank and blank -> Not okay
Expected Result 0 and 13

How do I have to change my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var pat = /t=(?:(\d+)m)?(\d+)s/;
```

This allows for the first part, including the `m` to be optional. Now in your second case, `$1` should be an empty string.

The `(?:` makes sure, that you do not get another captured string containing the `m`.

This will work, too, and do pretty much the same:

```
var pat = /t=(\d*?)m?(\d+)s/;
```

Here we just allow the first string of digits to be empty, and `m` to be optional. Just make sure to use `?` after the `*` to make the repetition ungreedy - otherwise the `1` will be matched by the first repetition, `m` will be left out, and the `3` will be matched by the second repetition.